# EXT2 Directory Content

Tags: c, directory, ext2

Hi I reached inode 2 , the root directory. I know the direct block number of it, which is 265.  How can I list the content of the root directory in C?

Comment: This question is badly written. It should be made clear that it is about **directly** editing a partition by editing the block-special file, without even mounting the partition. Also, WHY? :-)

Answer (score -1):

This should work. I suggest looking up the man pages for opendir() and readdir(). This is *not* based on inodes. Do you require to be able to look up directories based on inode?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main() {
        DIR *dir = opendir("/");
        if(dir==NULL) {
                perror("Couldn't open dir");
                exit(1);
        }
        printf("opened\n");
        struct dirent * entry;
        while((entry = readdir(dir))) {
                printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need to directly modify the low level filesystem without OS calls, do you know how to access directory inodes? See: [My Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287606/how-do-i-read-and-traverse-inodes)